# How to create a reusable picklist component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, picklist, html, dynamic

I have created a lightning web component which is a pick-list. My intention is to pass objectApiName and fieldApiName as parameters and then render UI accordingly. So that I can reuse this component in the future.

Following is my Code.

### GenericPicklist.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

import CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Object__c.Field_Name__c';

export default class GenericPicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api fieldApiName;
    @api label;
    @api value;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })
    objectInfo

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: CUSTOM_FIELD})
    CustomFieldPicklistValues;

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

### GenericPicklist.html

```
<template>
    <template if:true={recordTypeId}>
            <p>New, Completed</p>
    </template>
    <template if:true={CustomFieldPicklistValues.data}>
            <lightning-combobox
                label={label}
                value={value}
                placeholder="Choose ..."
                options={CustomFieldPicklistValues.data.values}
                onchange={handleChange} >
            </lightning-combobox>
    </template>
</template>
```

As you can see I was able to use `objectApiName` variable but I was not able to use `fieldApiName`. When I use `fieldApiName` variable UI is not rendered properly.

`CUSTOM_FIELD` object is as follows

```
{
    "objectApiName" : "Object__c",
    "fieldApiName"  : "Field_Name__c"
}
```

I tried to pass above object to `getPicklistValues` using parameters. Then it did not work. But when I pass the same object with hard coded values as follows, it worked.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: {"objectApiName" : "Object__c","fieldApiName"  : "Field_Name__c"}})
CustomFieldPicklistValues;
```

Am I doing any mistake? Why I cannot achieve this using parameters as below.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: {"objectApiName" : '$objectApiName',"fieldApiName"  : '$fieldApiName'}})
CustomFieldPicklistValues;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Field API structure is like

```
{
  "fieldApiName":"Type",
  "objectApiName":"Account"
}
```

I updated the code it may help you and it is working as expected to me.

**HTML Code**

```
<template>
    <div if:true={options}>
            <lightning-combobox
                label={picklistlabel}
                value={value}
                placeholder="--None--"
                options={options}
                onchange={handleChange} >
            </lightning-combobox>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class GenericPicklist extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
    @api fieldApiName;

    @track value;
    @track options;
    @track picklistlabel;

    recordTypeId;
    objfiedAPIName;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })
    objectInfo(result) {
        if(result.data) {
            this.picklistlabel = result.data.fields[this.fieldApiName].label;

            this.objfiedAPIName = {};
            this.objfiedAPIName.fieldApiName = result.data.fields[this.fieldApiName].apiName;
            this.objfiedAPIName.objectApiName = result.data.apiName;

            this.recordTypeId = result.data.defaultRecordTypeId;

        }
        else if(result.error) {
            window.console.log('error ===> '+JSON.stringify(result.error));
        }
    }

  @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: '$objfiedAPIName'})
    picklistValues({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            window.console.log('values ===> '+JSON.stringify(data));

            let picklistOptions = [{ label: '--None--', value: '--None--'}];

            // Picklist values
            data.values.forEach(key => {
                picklistOptions.push({
                    label: key.label, 
                    value: key.value
                })
            });

            this.options = picklistOptions;

        } else if (error) {
            window.console.log('error ===> '+error);
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }
}
```

**Configuration File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="reusepicklistinlwc">
    <apiVersion>46.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>

    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="objectApiName" type="String" default="Account" label="Enter the Object Name"/>
            <property name="fieldApiName" type="String" default="" label="Enter Field API Name"/>
        </targetConfig>
      </targetConfigs>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically import a field like this:
`import CUSTOM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Object__c.Field_Name__c';`

In general, I would recommend using lightning-record-form with lightning input field to achieve the requested functionality.

Comment: Don't think about `import` statement. Could you please present a reason why I cannot use parameters in second **wired property**. In first property I was able use `objectApiName` parameter. But I cannot use it in second property.